# Can not share the the title and description using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to share the title, image and description on click the social media buttons. But my code has some errors. I am not identify the solution, please assist me.

```
<div class="blog-post">
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="wrapPost">
            <div class="blog-img">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://ecom.sofizar.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/270x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/r/o/rovigo3.jpg" alt="Lorem" >
            </div>
            <div class="bl-details">
                <h4><a class="pro_URL" href="http://ecom.sofizar.com/rocker-wp-boots/">Spyke SP001 Rocker Motorcycle Boots (Rocker WP Boots)</a></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="socialMedia">
            <a class="fbook" title="Facebook" href="//www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" onclick="fbShare=window.open(this.href+encodeURIComponent(window.location), 'fbShare', 'toolbar = no, status = no, width = 640, height = 400, scrollbars=no'); return false;">&nbsp;</a> 

            <a class="twitter" title="Twitter" href="//twitter.com/home?status=" onclick="tweetShare=window.open(this.href+encodeURIComponent(window.location)+'&text='+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML)+'&url='+location.href+'&via=MaximoMoto','tweetShare','toolbar=no,status=no,width=600,height=400,scrollbars=no'); return false;" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a>

            <a class="googlePlus" title="googlePlus" href="//plus.google.com/share?url=" onclick="gplus=window.open(this.href+encodeURIComponent(window.location),'gplus','toolbar=no,status=no,width=600,height=300,scrollbars=no'); return false;" target="_blank"></a>

            <a class="pinterest" title="Pinterest" href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=&media=&description=" onclick="pinterest = window.open(this.href + encodeURIComponent(window.location), 'toolbar = no, status = no, width = 640, height = 400, scrollbars = no'); return false;" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a>

        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hassaan39/5932s6zx/)

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please be specific.

Comment: "But my code has some errors." this is very vague.  Can you describe what you want to do (expected results) and what you are getting instead (actual results)? Otherwise, the solution could be "make it work" which is not very helpful is it? - ALSO, your fiddle does not contain any Javascript.  How do you expect it to work?  Please create an [mcve] for us to assist you

Comment: On clicking the facebook button, I want to get share href value of class pro_URL. and Image of blog_img.
but this time wrong href value shares

Comment: your code is almost wrong, you are trying to share the current url by getting `(window.location)`, not the `pro_URL` !, also why are you trying to get the text of your social media anchors `document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML` ?!!

Comment: I just colored the sharing anchors to be shown http://jsfiddle.net/x4fL35sr/